# Display loading image and hide it

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In my application, when the user clicks on item’s name within one custom element (navigator-element), the item is loaded as another custom element (main-element). This loading can take time depending on the size of the item, as there may be many nested items within it. To let the user know that loading is in process, I want to show a spinner.

Here is how I am currently attempting to achieve this:

In main-element, I have one div which contains the spinner image, and has a `hidden?="{{!loading}}"` attribute.

When the user clicks an item’s name in the navigator-element, the variable `bool loading` is turned to true, and when loading is done  and all nested custom elements have been attached, the application turns `loading` to false.

However, the spinner div never gets displayed, even though the `loading` does change to true and then to false, correctly.  It seems that Polymer is suppressing intermediate UI changes until all are complete

If I include a button, clicking on which toggles the value of `loading`, the change are displayed correctly.

I also removed all `unresolved` attributes from everywhere in my application to see if it matters, however it made no difference.

What must I do to display spinner div, when a long duration process is underway?

Comment: Günter: I will be happy to share, but I am worried it is a bit complex.  I just created a branch which you can find here: https://gitlab.com/proteme/Learnia2/tree/spinner

Comment: A deployed version can be found here: http://proteme.org/Chekov/

Comment: A minimal reproducible example, stripped of all unrelated code would be great.

Comment: I wonder what you expect the binding expressions (`{{...}}`) in `index. html` to do.They only work within a Polymer element or an `auto-binding-dart` tag.

Comment: You are right, they have to be removed. They are the vestiges of past. And did not cause any harm so I didn't look at them. There is lot of cleaning up required, I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can fix this by just waiting one animation frame between setting `loading = true`, and doing the more expensive operation. If you do it all at once the browser won't render anything new until all your work is done because you are blocking the ui thread.